# Swift: Closure with Known Types Syntax

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to understand the syntax behind Known Types Closures.

Below is an example:

```
func applyMutliplication(value: Int, multiFunction: Int -> Int) -> Int {
    return multiFunction(value)
}

applyMutliplication(2, multiFunction: {value in
    value * 3  // returns a 6
})
```

I am struggling with `multiFucntion: Int -> Int`. Is this the same as `(multiFunction: Int) -> Int`?

When I try I try the following signature in playground, I get an error:

```
//below gives an error
func applyMutliplication(value: Int, ((multiFunction: Int) -> Int)) -> Int {
    return multiFunction(value)
}
```

My understanding is:
`applyMultiplication` takes in an `Int` called `value`, and a closure called `multiFunction` that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. `applyMultiplication` also returns `Int`

But then I am confused with as to how does `{value in value * 3}` causes it to return a `6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiFucntion: Int -> Int.` is *not* `(multiFunction: Int) -> Int?`

`multiFunction` is a function parameter name, it does not have anything to do with the type. The type is just `(Int) -> Int`. A function that has one `Int` parameter and returns an `Int`.

You are passing a closure that returns its parameter multiplied by `3` and you are passing it `2` as its parameter. The result is logically `6`.

Maybe it could be more readable this way:

```
func applyMutliplication(value: Int, multiFunction: Int -> Int) -> Int {
    return multiFunction(value)
}

let multiplyByThree: (Int) -> Int = {value in
    value * 3  // returns a 6
}

applyMutliplication(2, multiFunction: multiplyByThree)
```